# While trying to alter table I got "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query return me search results from multiple tables.
I'm reading this [tutorial](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm)

In phpmyadmin I wrote

```
ALTER TABLE files ADD FULLTEXT(title, desc);
```

it returned me

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc)' at line 1
```

Comment: You are not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9C%231064+-+You+have+an+error+in+your+SQL+syntax%E2%80%9D

Comment: I checked this but this wasn't about "alter".

Comment: That's because the error is not specifically related to `alter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `desc` is a column name, then you should try backticks around it as it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE files ADD FULLTEXT(title, `desc`);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer. It's good practice to add backticks around all your database, table and column names to ensure you're not running into conflicts like these.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. How did you write this character ` ? I copied it but couldn't find it in keyboard.

Comment: @TarekHassan on my keyboard it is on the key next to the 1.

Comment: On mine too but didn't notice it before. Thank you.

Comment: @bluefeet this caused an error too

" SELECT title, desc FROM projects WHERE MATCH (title, ` desc `) AGAINST ('press') "

How to silve it ?

Comment: you need to use backticks around any of the reserved words. To be safe, you should use them around all table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Actual syntax is like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
```

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: That would be to add a new column; he's trying to add a FULLTEXT index on existing columns. As an aside, I recommend not linking to w3schools as it is riddled with misinformation and terrible practice examples.  Here is the [mysql manual page for alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE files 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX inx1
(title, desc);
```